# please help figure out the error in this sigma sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, sums-of-squares

the question is "the sum of all possible products of the first n natural numbers taken two at a time is?"
and this is how I approached it:

first i selected the first number as 1

therefore $\Sigma$ 1*n = 2+3+4+5......n = (n-1)(n+2)/2

then selected 2 as first number

$\Sigma$ 2*n = 6+8=10+12....2n = (n-2)(2n+6)/2

then selected 3

$\Sigma$ 3*n= 12+15+18+21......3n = (n-3)(3n+12)/2
and so on, so the general term of the *sums* is (n-k)(kn+k(k=1)), where k varies from 1 to
n-1. treating n as a constant

so the sum of all possible products is $\Sigma$ (n-k)(kn+k(k=1)), where k varies from 1 to n-1.
solving that we get n(n-1)(n+1)(3n+2)/24

but the given answer is n(n+1)(2n-1)(n+3)/24

Comment: The given answer is incorrect as the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n-1)(n+3)}{24}$ does not guarantee an output in $\mathbb{N}$. For a more detailed look at why your answer is correct and an example showing the computation for a given $n$, refer to the answer I left!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we begin by noting the following sum:

$$\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + 2\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(i+1)}_\text{this is the sum we want}$$

Here, the first two sums have well-known results (these results can also be proven by induction) as follows:
$$\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Now, to get the sum we want, we simply subtract these values, like so:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(i+1) &=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n i^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{4}\right)\cdot \left[\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-\frac{2n+1}{3}\right]\\
&=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{4}\right)\cdot \frac{3n^2-n-2}{6}\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)\cdot(3n^2-3n+2n-2)}{24}\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)\cdot(3n+2)(n-1)}{24}
\end{align*}
Thus, your answer is correct and we can see a quick example:

Consider the following sum, for $n=4$:
$$1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 3+1\cdot 4 + 2\cdot 3 + 2\cdot 4 + 3\cdot 4 = 35$$
Then, we have:
$$\frac{n(n+1)\cdot(3n+2)(n-1)}{24} = \frac{4\cdot 5\cdot 14\cdot 3}{24}=35$$
$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n-1)(n+3)}{24} = \frac{4\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 6}{24} = \frac{980}{24}\approx 40.8333$$
Note that when using the "given answer", an integer is not guaranteed, which is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Note That

$$S_n = 1(2+3+...+n)+2(3+4+...+n)+...+ (n-1)(n) =$$

$$S_{n-1}+n(1+2+3+....+n-1)$$

$$ S_{n} = S_{n-1} +(n)\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$$

Thus the sum is $$ S_n=\sum _{k=2}^n \frac {(k-1)k^2}{2}=\sum _{k=2}^n \frac {k^3-k^2}{2}=\frac {n(n+1)(n-1)(3n+2)}{24}$$

For example, $$S_4 = 35 $$
$$S_5= 85 $$